# Firebase Structure

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, nosql

I am writing my first flutter and firebase app and I am a little confused on how best to structure the database. Below I have put a brief description of what I want the app to do... its a learning app based on Flash Cards.

I want to have FlashCards which will have the Question and Answer fields. The FlashCards will all be assigned to a Book and then when they are loaded the user will always have to select a Book to study and then this will list all cards in the book. Then I want to make it so that multiple users can have access to that same book.

So in a real world example, a child could have a science test so he creates a Book called "Aug 2020 Science", then he adds many cards to the book with the Questions and Answers... then once he completes the book, he could share it with his friends and they all have the same 'book' to study.

In SQL I would create tbl_Cards, tbl_Books, tbl_Users, tbl_UsersBooks (tbl_UsersBooks would just have a table that shows the ID's for the User and the Book). So a user can have many books, a book can have many users and many cards.

In SQL I could just show relational data from each table and just filter the UserBooks to show current user. However, I am understanding if I had this structure in firebase I would pretty much be pulling every document and collection each time a user logs in.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

books collection:

- ${bookId}:

  - bookName: (string)
  - createdBy: (userId)
  - cards collection:

    - ${cardId}:

      - answer: (string)
      - question: (string)

In firebase cloud firestore for flutter (and any other platform/framework that can use firestore), you can do some simple queries to only load specific types of documents. In flutter, you can make a query like this:

```
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

final query = db.collection('books').where('createdBy', isEqualTo: userId);
```

You could get all of those documents by calling

```
query.get();
```

Or you could listen to realtime updates like this:

```
query.snapshots.listen((querySnapshot) {
 
  ...

});
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Hey, thanks! But how does this account for the share of the book to a friend? I was thinking of maybe having a map in the book of AllowedUsers... then having the field name be the userID and it be a bool and set to true when the user is allowed. I think I can then query arrayContains on the AllowedUsers. 

The other issue, if I want to just list the books, am I correct in thinking that I am then pulling all the cards as well... so say a user has 10 books each with 50 cards... to list the users books I will be doing 510 reads as it will be pulling the books and all collections below?

Comment: The allowed users could just be a list of the userIds that are allowed. In cloud firestore for flutter, you have document references and document snapshots. A document reference is kind of like the path for the document you want to get. You create a document reference like this: `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionId').doc('documentId');`. When you call `documentReference.get();`, you get a document snapshot the data for that document only, not for the collections that are inside the document (like the cards collection). I am running out of words - I'll finish in next comment

Comment: If you want to get the cards collection in the book document after you have gotten the data, you can get the reference for that docuentSnapshot like this: `docuentSnapshot.reference`. Then you do this: `booksDocReference.collection('cards').get();`.